# SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement while preparing a general leder

Tags: php, sqlite

Sqlite provides the result correctly, but when I use the code in PHP, it gives a warning that `SQLite3::query()`: Unable to prepare statement.

this warning is due to the use of `OVER(ORDER BY)` command. if I remove this php display the result, but when I use the OVER, it gives the error. and i am not getting any idea how to fix this.

```
$sql="SELECT trandate, type, particulars, custid, custname, debit, credit, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN trandate = '$opdate' 
                      THEN $totop+debit 
                      ELSE debit-credit
                 END) 
             OVER(ORDER BY date(substr(trandate, 7, 4)
                                || '-' || substr(trandate, 4, 2) 
                                || '-' || substr(trandate, 1, 2)
                               ) ASC
                 ) AS balance, notes 
      FROM inboundtrans 
      WHERE custid ='$customer' and type!='$type' 
      ORDER BY datetime(substr(trandate, 7, 4)
                        || '-' || substr(trandate, 4, 2) 
                        || '-' || substr(trandate, 1, 2)) ASC";

$query = $con->query($sql);                           
     while ($row = $query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {                              
                        echo "
                          <tr>
                          <td>{$row['trandate']}</td>
                          <td>{$row['type']}</td> 
                          <td>{$row['particulars']}</td> 
                          <td>{$row['debit']}</td> 
                          <td>{$row['credit']}</td>
                          <td>{$row['balance']}</td>
                          <td>{$row['notes']}</td>     
                          </tr>\n";
                      }
```

Error Displayed

> Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "(":
>   syntax error in C:\My Themes\storelite\www\ledView.php on line 188
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on
>   boolean in C:\My Themes\storelite\www\ledView.php:190 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\My Themes\storelite\www\ledView.php on line 190

Comment: Are you using Sqlite 3.25 or newer? Anything before that version doesn't understand window functions.

Comment: I am using SQLite Version 3.27.2

Comment: Then either it was built without window function support (Possible but unlikely), or there's some other issue. You left out the actual error message and didn't format your post... do those so it's readable and somebody might spot a problem.

Comment: sure I will edit the question

Comment: I have Edited the question and added the actual code, I know that the error is because of Over clause. But I have no idea to remove the error

Comment: Yup, that's the error you get from old versions of sqlite. Are you absolutely sure your php installation is using the version you think it is? You checked the version from in php with `SQLite3::version()`?

Comment: yes, that's right. I checked the version and its give me Array ( [versionString] => 3.15.1 [versionNumber] => 3015001 ) Current PHP version: 7.1.3

Comment: I am using PHPDesktop, So how I will Update the sqlite to current version in that, or I just rebuild the database???